# Facebook share button shares same link as Like button?

Tags: html, facebook, button, plugins, share

I am using the facebook share plugin for the first time and I can't see that I'm doing wrong.

I am using their Like/Share buttons but can not get the share button to share the link that is placed in the OG:url tag, it shares the link that is also linked to the Like button.

I added

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="https:///" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content=" | „" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="....." />
<meta property="og:image"         content="/img/BG.png" />
```

and it still doesn't work.

The Like/Share div looks like this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https:/" data-width="" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`data-href` is not supposed to be your Facebook page. `data-href` should be the current page the widget is on, and [according to the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/), should be the same as the open graph `<meta property="og:url" />` content attribute:

> og:url and data-href should use the same URL.

The open graph meta tags are really just meant for sites that need meta information about the page for generating previews - they are not even strictly necessary for the like button (but you should still keep/use them).

If you want to encourage page likes, you might want the [Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Check the code href-data and  og:url should contain same url of your site
check out this example of share/like button from Facebook developers site itself.

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="https://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
<div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="https://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
    data-layout="button_count">
  </div>
```